# I don't want magento Frontend Customers Session to log out Automatically except they logout it manually

Tags: magento-1.9, customer-account, session, customer-session

If My Website Frontend Customers once login (Not Backend Admin Users), they should not be logged out Automatically. If they manually logout Then only it should be logged out.

I want this because if any registered customer comes to my site and view any product or add to cart then I can send them emails.

Please suggest if it is Possible.

This is my Current setting 
In Magento Admin 
[image]

In php.ini file
[image]

magento version : 1.9.2.0

Answer (score 2):

Go to System -> Configuration -> Web -> Session Cookie management and set it to the value you need in the correct store view or if you have only one, in the default config.

Also keep in mind this has to be the same or lower than session.gc_maxlifetime in your PHP config. 0 should give you an endless session.

Comment: I don't want customers to log out at any time until he logs out manually.

Comment: Thst is what 0 do.

Comment: Thank you very Much for your help, One quick question, that it is only for magento frontend users i.e. customers not admins, Right?

Comment: Yes. Remember to mark the answer as accepted if it helped you.

Comment: Hello mbalparda, Its not working, I am getting logged out automatically. Can you please advice?

Comment: Please check this config http://prntscr.com/c9bx4r

Comment: Have you changed your PHP config too? Check the created cookie with the debug tool you use and see the lifetime there.

Comment: I have only made this change System -> Configuration -> Web -> Session Cookie management -> Cookie Lifetime -> 0
Nothing else. Which tool I need to use Bro?

Comment: That will depend on your hosting. This can be set in the php.ini but if you are running on a shared hosting you will have to ask them to change this for you.

Comment: What I need to change in php.ini?

Comment: It's in the answer.

Comment: pls check the updated question

Comment: i have done all the setting according to you